# Problemas con permisos Bluetooth - Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, permisos, bluetooth

estoy teniendo un problema con una app de flutter que estoy desarrollando. Incluye el paquete bluetooth_print 3.0.1 en el cual al momento de invocar al metodo starScan() para empezar a buscar los dispositivos bluetooth cercanos la app se detiene diciendo que falta el permiso bluetooth_SCAN (que debería ir en el manifest.xml). El problema es que ya está incluido en el archivo y sigue persistiendo el error. Alguien me puede guiar por favor?
[image: El error que muestra el debug]

[image: El archivo AndroidManifest.xml]

Comment: El código y los mensajes de error siempre _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Puede que además de indicarlo en el manifest, sea necesario pedirle al usuario explícitamente permisos para usar el bluotooth.

Este package, te puede servir: https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler

Lista de permisos: https://pub.dev/documentation/permission_handler_platform_interface/latest/permission_handler_platform_interface/Permission-class.html#constants

Permiso que creo que necesitas:

```
bluetoothScan → const Permission
Android: Allows the user to look for Bluetooth devices (e.g. BLE peripherals). iOS: Nothing
Permission._(28)
```